# What are some texts ( or sects ) which declare Devī Sarasvati as Supreme.?

Tags: brahman, sects, saraswati

All the five deities - (Brahmā, Vishnu-Lakshmi, Shiva-Uma) within the *Tridev-Tridevī* continuum, enjoys a *Brahman* or the Supreme deity status either explicitly (with dedicated sects) or implicitly (in some texts/verses or as a 'parallel-supreme' with their consorts).

Except Devī Saraswatī (according to, as far as my knowledge is concerned).

**My question is:**
Are there any references in any scriptures (or sects) which eulogies Devi Sarasvati as the Supreme, either in her own right or as a 'parallel-consort' ?
Are there any related *sampradāyas* dedicated to Devī Saraswatī? If yes, then I'd please like to know all the related details about them.

Comment: You can have a look at 2 related (not dup) questions: 1. [Does Adishankara mention Saraswati as Parabrahnan](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/43153/did-shankaracharya-mention-saraswati-as-para-brahman?r=SearchResults); 2. [Are there any sects for Lakshmi or Saraswati](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11031/are-there-sects-for-lakshmi-or-saraswati?r=SearchResults); 3. [Who is goddess Gayatri? Is she Saraswati in Parashakti (Brahman) form?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/43169/who-is-goddess-gayatri-is-she-another-form-of-saraswati-or-saraswati-in-parasha)

Answer (score 2):

Chapter 32 of Vamana purana has a detailed eulogy of Sarasvati by Markandeya where she is praised as brahman. Here are some excerpts-

[image]

[image]

The complete eulogy can be read [here](https://archive.org/details/vamanapuranavaishnavaupapuranasanskritenglishocr/page/n183/mode/2up?view=theater).

Answer (score 1):

There are many verses describing Maa Saraswati as Adi Para-Shakti or Para-Brahma or [Prana/Atma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/52286/20968). For example.:

The Shandilya Upanishad of Atharvana Veda describes Maa Saraswati as the tridevis and also the pranava AUM, mentions the below.:

> ***Sitting in the paḍma posture, the person should meditate that there is at the tip of his nose Gāyaṭrī, a girl of red complexion surrounded by the numberless rays of the image of the moon and mounted on a hamsa (swan) and having a mace in her hand. She is the visible symbol of the letter A. The letter U has as its visible symbol Sāviṭrī, a young woman of white colour having a disk in her hand and riding on a garuda (eagle). The letter M has as its visible symbol Sarasvaṭī, an aged woman of black colour riding on a bull, having a trident in her hand.***

I hope this clarifies your queries.